# Using values from a list to perform re.sub() in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am attempting to learn Regex in order to handle some text processing better. However, I'm having some trouble when trying to match a list of words all at once.

Essentially, I am trying to match all of the words from the nltk stopwords corpus, and suck them out of a file (an e-mail, in this case) so that I can do some analysis on the remaining words.

my code is thus:

```
import re
import email
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

mailfile = open("a lot to love.eml", "r+", encoding= 'utf-8')

stop = stopwords.words('english')

message = email.message_from_file(mailfile)

if message.is_multipart():
    payload = message.get_payload(0)
else:
    payload = message.get_payload()

strload = str(payload)  

a = re.sub('\b%s' %('\b|\b'.join[stop], strload))

print(a)

mailfile.close()
```

The error I get when I run this is:

```
  File "RegEx.py", line 30, in <module>
    a = re.sub('\b%s' %('\b|\b'.join[stop], strload))
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I thought I was close with the .join. Other solutions I've seen have suggested using lambda, but I'm not familiar with the method... Is there a way to make this work using .join? Or do I need to suck it up and use lambda?

Definitely open to other suggestions of how I could do this with regex, if there's something I'm missing please let me know.

Comment: Try `join(stop)` instead of `join[stop]`.

Comment: Still throws "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" though.

Comment: Probably a misplaced parenthesis. How about: `a = re.sub('\b%s' %('\b|\b'.join(stop)), strload)`

Comment: Apparently I suck at formatting. That's totes right. It doesn't give me what I want but at least it runs now. Thanks Kevin!

Comment: That should be `r"\b%s\b"`, to require a word boundary after the final word. Though it's simpler to just build `r"\b(word|word|word)\b"`.

Comment: `re.sub` takes 3 arguments, you provided (an illegal) one...